# ValueConverter for String to String

Tags: string, grails, valueconverter

I need to perform additional modifying of all Strings, is it possible to make a ValueConverter with a Target Type of `String`, or if not, in what other way can I do it?

```
class StringValueConverter implements ValueConverter {
    @Override
    boolean canConvert(Object value) {
        value instanceof String
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object value) {
       //modifying value
    }

    @Override
    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        return String
    }
}
```

I need to do it before binding

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: @Vladimir: What happened to this issue? Has it been resolved? I need something similar.

Comment: @sola I create class that extends DataBindingListenerAdapter

Comment: @sola [link](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/grails/databinding/events/DataBindingListenerAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Groovy yes you can. There are various ways:

Using [Extension Module](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Creating+an+extension+module) is one of them.

Another way would be to use runtime metaprogramming, for example:

```
String.metaClass.flip = {
    delegate.reverse()
}

assert "Hello".flip() == "olleH"
```

Above is a contrived example of adding methods to metaClass of String, but a convert method as in your example can fit in as well.

However, the extension module is what can be robust in your case if you are looking for adding sanity by `canConvert` which would not be needed for runtime metaClass methods as they are only available for `String` class.